# date time plotting in highcharts

Tags: datetime, plot, highcharts

I have 15 min interval date wise data to plot.
Dates might not be consistent in my case.

**Sample format:
var row = ["2012-02-29", " 00:15", "0"]**

I am getting the array from Java class for plotting.

**I tried a few options like :**

```
    var tempVal = new Array();

    for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++){

        var record = row[i].split(",");
        tempVal[i]=Date.UTC(record[0].substring(0,4), record[0].substring(5,7),   record[0].substring(8,10), record[1].substring(1,3), record[1].substring(4,7)), record[2];

}
```

**In Highcharts : 
    series: [{
       data: tempVal
     }]**

But i am unable to plot this on Highcharts.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To plot a date time on HighCharts you need a date time value and a y value.
It should look something like the following:

```
data: [
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9], 
                [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 71.5], 
                [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 106.4]
            ]
```

Or your could replace `Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1)` with the equivalent javascript time value.

`Date.UTC()` can accept several different formats. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp).

So what you need to do is combine your date value and your time value into one single time value.

EDIT after looking at your example code you have a couple of issues. For one your data array `tempVal` is declared wrong. It should be:

```
var tempVal = [];
```

You should also be using `array.push` to get the data into the `tempVal` array.

The other issue is that your time series does not appear to be in chronological order - when I had your series set up correctly I got the area "line" going back and forth.

All that being said what I came up with is that you need to fix your data array declaration and how you are assigning data to that array. This is a very simple method and it can of course be made faster but I like verbose:

```
for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    var record = row[i].split(",");
    var xVal = Date.UTC(parseInt(record[0].substring(0, 4)), parseInt(record[0].substring(5, 7)), parseInt(record[0].substring(8, 10)), parseInt(record[1].substring(1, 3)), parseInt(record[1].substring(4, 7)));
    var yVal = Math.random() * 10;
    var x = [xVal, yVal];
    tempVal.push(x);
}
```

See updated example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/QcFW7/5/). Note that the lines go back and forth - as I said this has to do with your time series not being in chronological order. Also note that months are 0-based so Jan = 0 and Dec = 11.

Comment: Thanks but i did try putting in the date and time in Date.UTC() but still it doesn't plot anything. The data is 15-min interval data but dates might not be consistent. Please advise

Comment: the fact that the "dates might not be consistent" is not important. We are going to see a bit more code or even better a representative jsFiddle showing some example data and the issue you are facing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine now. I hope i don't get into any further issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have errors in console? If you have code you posted, you should have one.

Regarding Highcharts - it is required to values should be numbers, not strings, soe for example: `record[2]` should be parsed before, for example: `parseFloat(record[2])`

Comment: Please look at my [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983248/need-help-in-plotting-a-chart-using-highcharts-in-angularjs)